# jre1.7.0_11\java_sp.dll is corrupt what to do?

Tags: windows-7, java

I redownloaded the installer several time.

My problem is exactly like this guy:

http://www.spywareinfoforum.com/index.php?/topic/134584-java-installer-error/

Moreover, also like this guy I can't uninstall Java. I can't update java. I can't access bbm. Java icon doesn't show up on my task manager.

Also the most advance Java is 7.11 and this one is blocked by firefoex. Am I correct here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**JavaRa**](http://singularlabs.com/software/javara/) might help you in a situation like this:

> JavaRa is an effective way to deploy, update and remove the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). Its most significant feature is the JRE Removal tool; which forcibly deletes files, directories and registry keys associated with the JRE. This can assist in repairing or removing Java when other methods fail.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

On Java.com, on the left, click on the link that says "Error Messages". Find and click on the link that says "Download errors: java_sp.dll is corrupt, 1305, 2755, 1606". In the Solution, click on "download offline installer". There's a bug that corrupts Java updating online. So this little program from Java itself prevents that corruption from happening. Worked great for me and I didn't have to mess with my registry or install non-Java programs.

Comment: https://java.com/en/download/windows_offline.jsp