# Java JRE does not uninstall or reinstall

Tags: java

I need to update to the latest version of Java, but it tells me that Java has already been installed. When I try to reinstall it, it says that Java is not installed.

Revo Uninstall, CCleaner and manual removal all fail.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Old JRE Installation Issue](http://superuser.com/questions/483365/java-old-jre-installation-issue), [jre1.7.0\_11\java\_sp.dll is corrupt what to do?](http://superuser.com/questions/538538/jre1-7-0-11-java-sp-dll-is-corrupt-what-to-do) etc.

Comment: Using programs like that it is no wonder you are having problems!

Answer (score 3):

Use [JavaRA](http://singularlabs.com/software/javara/), to remove Java even if there are issues. It will even install the latest version automatically.

[image]